# How to show that $C_G(a)=N_G(a)$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

For singleton sets, then  how  show to that  $C_G(a)=N_G(a)$?

As  I know something about singleton set that is its  closed  in real line. Now I'm confused  that  how  can I relate  this  concept in group theory.

I found this  article  on http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Centralizer_and_normalizer

Any hints/solution will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in G$. We have

\begin{align}
x\in C_G(a)&\iff ax=xa\\
&\iff \{a\}x=x\{a\}\quad (\text{as sets})\\
&\iff x\in N_G(a).
\end{align}

Hence $C_G(a)=N_G(a)$.

Comment: Does that make sense to you, @jasmine?

Comment: thanks u @shaun

Comment: You're welcome, @jasmine :)